# Adding UIView programmatically, but the other views resize and there's artefacting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I'm building an app for iPad that involved adding UIViews programmatically. When the view is loading, I can add other UIViews just fine. However, after the UI's loaded, when I try to create a UIView programmatically and add it to, say, the corner, the other UIViews shift and the view doesn't redraw (so the older positions/sizes of the other UIViews and widgets are also drawn).

Any ideas on what I should be doing to avoid this issue?

EDIT: The code that resizes the panel that's giving me issue is in a function that gets called when a button is pressed. The meat of the function is this:

```
CGRect fooPanelFrame = CGRectMake(fBasePanelWidth,
                                  50,
                                  fBasePanelWidth,
                                  panelHeight);

[_fooPanelView setFrame:fooPanelFrame];
```

Where 'fooPanelView' is of type UIView. This is the only one that gets resized after everything gets constructed. The other UIViews get resized (in a similar fashion) in the 'viewDidLayoutSubViews' method.

EDIT: This is what the UI looks like before:

[image: before frame resized]

and this is what it looks like after the central frame is re-sized:

[image: after frame resized]

The blue color is just the color of the root UIView.

Another point to note is that, when I log the size of the view that I'm changing, before the resize, the values are what I'd expect, but not after. In my testing, I'm deliberately setting it to all 20s, but the value for the frame coming back isn't that. I wonder if this means that there's some setting in the super view that I need to change...

Comment: are you setting autoresizing masks on any of the views?

Comment: No, not in the code, at any rate.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: autoLayout is turned off in the view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to be due to my own darn stupidity. I didn't realise that the viewDidLayoutSubviews(...) method gets called again when I did my button press (my resizing is done in a function the button event handler calls). Are there any design patterns for situations where a UIView gets resized? For now, I'm exiting from the viewDidLayoutSubviews(...)  method if the view's drawn and I'm just resizing stuff.

Comment: Please start a new Question for a new problem.